How to make MatDialog transparent and center its item
I am copying example from Angular Material Progress Spinner: display as overlay
The dialog component, app/progress-spinner-dialog.component.html:
<mat-spinner align="'center" [color]="color" [diameter]="diameter" [mode]="mode" [strokeWidth]="strokeWidth" [value]="value"></mat-spinner>

app/progress-spinner-dialog.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ProgressSpinnerMode } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { ThemePalette } from '@angular/material/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-progress-spinner-dialog',
  templateUrl: './progress-spinner-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./progress-spinner-dialog.component.css']
})
export class ProgressSpinnerDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() color?: ThemePalette;
  @Input() diameter?: number = 100;
  @Input() mode!: ProgressSpinnerMode;
  @Input() strokeWidth?: number;
  @Input() value?: number;
  @Input() backdropEnabled = true;
  @Input() positionGloballyCenter = true;
  @Input() displayProgressSpinner?: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}

Then in app.component.css
.transparent .mat-dialog-container {
    box-shadow: true;
    background-color: transparent;
    align-items: center;
}
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100% }
body { margin: 0; font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }

app.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { ProgressSpinnerDialogComponent } from "./progress-spinner-dialog/progress-spinner-dialog.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private dialog: MatDialog
  ) {
    let observable: Observable<string> = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        observer.next("done waiting for 5 sec");
        observer.complete();
      }, 5000); 
    });
    this.showProgressSpinnerUntilExecuted(observable);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  showProgressSpinnerUntilExecuted(observable: Observable<Object>) {
    let dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ProgressSpinnerDialogComponent> = this.dialog.open(ProgressSpinnerDialogComponent, {
      height: '40%',
      width: '40%',
      panelClass: 'transparent',
      disableClose: true
    });
    let subscription = observable.subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
        //handle response
        console.log(response);
        dialogRef.close();
      },
      (error) => {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
        //handle error
        dialogRef.close();
      }
    );
  }
}

app.module.ts:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { ProgressSpinnerDialogComponent } from './progress-spinner-dialog/progress-spinner-dialog.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProgressSpinnerDialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatDialogModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Now I have three problems:

I cannot make the MatDialog transparent;
I cannot adjust the spinner to be in the center of the diaglog;
I do not know how to adjust the size, color, mode of the spinner in the dialog.

I am using Angular 16. Please help.

Check customer styles
